# Android studio get element from website

Tags: javascript, android

I want to make an Android Application on Android studio that gets the balance from a site and shows it in an app. So I want to load the page in `WebView` and get the number as `String`, is there any way to do it like `getElementById()`?

Edit
This is the website source `<span id="balance">0.0</span>`
I am trying to get the 0.0

Comment: firstly, it does not relate to `android-studio`, as it does not matter which IDE you will use (android studio, notepad, or whatever). I think that JSOUP is what you need.

Comment: You need to provide some code of what you are doing and also more context. What balance? Something you are developing? What technologies are being used?

Comment: I highly recommend Jsoup as well, great webscraper.

Answer (score 0):

Android apps are written in Java. The getElementById method you mentioned however is a Javascript method. You can't just expect the two to work together. A webview doesn't help you with that either.

Instead, you need to parse the website yourself to get the value you want. Vlad's suggestion to use [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) looks promising, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

First, the webpage is yours?
if yes, create a json endpoint and use this to get data.
if no, create a server side HTML scraper from that URL, embed result in an endpoint, serve it to the app.

Imagine, if scraper is hard coded in app, page changes slightly, get's redesigned how do you update app? release a new one? better only update server side scraper.